# python - importing csv - filtering on column - writing to txt file w/ a timestamp - Output issues with txt

Tags: etl

First post, try not to get mad at my formatting.

I am trying to ETL on a csv file with python 3.5 - the code I have, successfully extracts, filters on correct column, creates the desired end result in the "new_string" variable and produces the correctly named txt file at end of run. But opening the txt file shows it is only one character long if it were an index i = [1] is only thing showing up, I was expecting the whole column to print out in a string format.. clearly I am not taking the formatting of the list/string into consideration but I am stuck for now.

If anyone sees something going on here. I would appreciate the heads up. Thanks in advance...

here is my code:

```
cdpath = os.getcwd()

def get_file_path(filename):
   currentdirpath = os.getcwd()
   file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
   print (file_path)
   return file_path

path = get_file_path('cleanme.csv')  ## My test file to work on

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'):   ##Time stamp func
     return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

def read_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rU') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
         new_list = row[2]
         new_string = str(new_list)
         print (new_string)

    with open(timeStamped('cleaned.txt'),'w') as outf:
        outf.write(new_string)
```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting based on how you had stuff set with newlines ... but I'm not a mind-reader, so I can't tell if you intended the with open(timeStamped('cleaned.txt'),'w') as outf: to be part of the for low above or not.  Although, actually, it doesn't matter all that much, as noted in my answer below

Comment: Also, welcome to SO, and if my answer doesn't actually answer what you were looking for, please provide an example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
def read_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rU') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
       for row in reader:
         new_list = row[2]
         new_string = str(new_list)
         print (new_string)

    with open(timeStamped('cleaned.txt'),'w') as outf:
        outf.write(new_string)
```

As noted in my comment above, there was some question on whether the second with was properly indented, but actually, it doesn't matter:

You generate the new_string inside the for loop (`for row in reader`).  But because you don't use it inside the loop (except printing it out), when the loop finishes, the only value you will have access to will be the last element.

Alternatively, if you had the `with ... as outf` as part of the loop, each time through, you'd open a new copy and overwrite the data, such that cleaned.txt only has the last value at the end again.

I think what you want is something like:

```
def read_csv(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'rU') as csvfile:
      with open(timeStamped('cleaned.txt'),'w') as outf:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
          new_list = row[2] #extract the 3rd column of each row
          new_string = str(new_list) # optionally do some transforms here
          print (new_string) #debug
          outf.write(new_string) #store result
```

Comment: Foon, Thanks dude!  That is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly.